# Positioning in HTML <button> tag

Tags: html, css, firefox, button, positioning

I'm trying to theme a search form with `button` and I have problem with text positioning in the `button`. Chrome and Opera are showing the button properly, but Firefox  is not.

**HTML:**

```
<button type="submit"><span>Search</span></button>
```

**CSS:**

```
button {
    border: 0;
    background: red;
    padding: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
button span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

In Opera and Chrome the `span` is at the top left corner. In Firefox the padding at top and left and the top position begins in the middle of the `button` height.

What am I doing wrong?

Live demo: http://doctype.n-joy.sk/button/

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this is your real CSS? You have defined rules for something **with class** "button", and not for the `<button>` tag.

Comment: it wasn't real css.. I removed the dot.. it was mistake only here. Live demo is here: http://doctype.n-joy.sk/button/

Answer (score 3):

That's a strange one. Looks like Firefox is keeping some kind of proprietary padding inside of button element. The workaround I was able to implement was a FF-only piece of CSS with a rather ugly negative margin for the span... A quick fix really, maybe others can follow with something better.

```
button {
  background: red;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
button span {
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
// FF only:
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    button span {
        margin: -1px -3px;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is not in this margin, but in that the absolute-position starts not from the top of the button element, but from the middle. A negative `top` property, with the value of half of the button's height would be a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for this workaround, but I don't like it that way. For now I wrapped the button with relative positioned div.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you did everything correctly, but there is some **dark magic** emerging from the default styles of Firefox, and from some undocumented, hidden (pseudo-)elements attached to buttons.

I haven't yet found the rule which would help you with this button issue, but you may try to scan the default styles yourself. If you type in Firefox's address bar: `resource://gre-resources/forms.css`, then you will see one of its default stylesheets.

Some of suspicious selectors (just wild guesses) are: `*|*::-moz-button-content` or `input > .anonymous-div`. The second one does not seem to be defined for `button`, but who knows where else the magic lies?

In any case, I suppose, you might report it as a **bug**.

Comment: Anyway, I found simple solution.. wrap the button to another div with position: relative and remove the position to the button.. look at the demo site again.. div#example1 is the 'old method' and the div#example2 is the 'new method'.

Comment: Oh, I found the bug already reported: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=437722 (Well.. **three years ago!**)

Answer (score 0):

Found this in Twitter Boostrap [reset.less](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/reset.less) file.
It corrects this behavior.

```
button,
input {
    *overflow: visible; // Inner spacing ie IE6/7
    line-height: normal; // FF3/4 have !important on line-height in UA stylesheet
}
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner { // Inner padding and border oddities in FF3/4
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Note that comments are in less... not CSS so you have to replace `//` by `/* ... */`